# "Get Started" button not working in Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

I recently setup the "Get Started" button using the following POST method using Postman:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<my token>
```

With the raw text:

```
{
  "get_started": {"payload": "<postback_payload>"}
}
```

It returns:

```
{
    "result": "success"
}
```

But nothing show up in my Messenger (deleted the chat already)

If I send the raw data to setup the greeting text, it works normally and showed up:

```
{
  "greeting": [
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "text":"Hello!" 
    }, {
      "locale":"en_US",
      "text":"Timeless apparel for the masses."
    }
  ]
}
```

Can somebody help me, thanks!

Comment: _“(deleted the chat already)”_ - not sure that is enough, the documentation says, _“The welcome screen is only shown the first time the user interacts with the Page on Messenger.”_ Try with a page you have not messaged with before at any point so far.

Comment: Hi, I tried with another facebook profile, still not working